# Genymotion emulator crashes when logging in

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-emulator, genymotion

My app crashes when trying to verify username and password from mySQL database (logging in). This is verified on an AsyncTask method. It works fine on the normal Eclipse emulator. Are there any settings or tweaks to be done? Does it crash coz of the AsyncTask, or is there any other factor?

Here's the logcat:

```
03-14 17:01:57.755: W/EGL_genymotion(2395): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at com.example.shareity.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:33)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at com.example.shareity.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:35)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at com.example.shareity.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:204)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at com.example.shareity.Login$ProcessLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     ... 17 more
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-14 17:03:00.862: W/System.err(2395):     ... 22 more
03-14 17:03:00.862: E/Buffer Error(2395): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 17:03:00.862: E/JSON Parser(2395): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-14 17:03:00.878: D/AndroidRuntime(2395): Shutting down VM
03-14 17:03:00.878: W/dalvikvm(2395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62d0288)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at com.example.shareity.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:210)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at com.example.shareity.Login$ProcessLogin.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 17:03:00.878: E/AndroidRuntime(2395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:08:00.935: I/Process(2395): Sending signal. PID: 2395 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post here your logcat?

Comment: @Fondesa, added logcat

Comment: The MySQL Server is probably refusing the connection "from" Genymotion emulator. Try adding the IP Address of emulator to "Allowed" IP Addresses in MySQL Server. I have very little used MySQL, so this may or may not work for you, but it's worth trying.

Comment: @KunalB., any idea how to allow an IP address on the mySQL server?

Comment: As I said I have not worked on MySQL much, but I would suppose it's a very standard thing & you can easily look on the Internet.